# SSL handshake throwing error, as server upgraded to TLSv1

Tags: ssl, handshake

Our tokenserver is upgraded to only accept the TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2 connections.  My code for handshake using SSL is failing. How to upgrade my code to suuport TLSv1 handshake? My java version is 1.6. Below is my SSL client code.

```
 public static void setTruststore(String truststorePath, String truststorePwd)
    {
        if( truststorePath != null && !truststorePath.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null") && truststorePath.trim().length() != 0 ){
            java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", truststorePath);
            if( truststorePwd != null && !truststorePwd.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null") && truststorePwd.trim().length() != 0 ){
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", truststorePwd.trim());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"));
    }

My token server already upgraded and we are failing to connect to it.

I edited my code to below to support TLSv1

package ml.token.utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyStore;  
import javax.net.SocketFactory;  
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;  
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;  
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;  
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory; 
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket; 
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.CertificateRequest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DefaultTlsClient;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsAuthentication;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsCredentials;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
// To be used for Ezi SSL certificate //
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.security.PrivilegedActionException;

public class TrustStore {

    public static void setTruststore(String truststorePath, String truststorePwd)
    {
         KeyStore ks = null;
         FileInputStream fis = null;
        try{
        char[] passwd = null;
    if (truststorePwd.length() != 0)
           passwd = truststorePwd.toCharArray();
        java.security.SecureRandom secureRandom = new java.security.SecureRandom();
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(truststorePath);
        ks.load(fis, passwd);
        fis.close();
          BouncyCastleProvider bcp = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        if( truststorePath != null && !truststorePath.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null") && truststorePath.trim().length() != 0 ){
             try {
        Security.addProvider(bcp);
        } catch (Exception e)   {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot add BouncyCastle security provider");
        }
             System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol");
             System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
             System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", truststorePath);

            if( truststorePwd != null && !truststorePwd.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null") && truststorePwd.trim().length() != 0 ){
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", truststorePwd.trim());
                System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");

            final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");  
            final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                    tmf.init(ks);
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(),secureRandom); 

            // get hold of the real underlying socket factory which is expected to do the real job
            final SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();  
            // "wrap" it around using our custom SSLSocketFactory so that we have control over the enabled protocols of newly created sockets
            final SSLSocketFactory wrappedFactory = new ProtocolOverridingSSLSocketFactory(factory, new String[] {"TLSv1"});
            byte[] ipAddr = new byte[] { 10, 2, 100, 79 };
             SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) wrappedFactory.createSocket(java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr), 8443);

            TlsClientProtocol protocol = new TlsClientProtocol(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream(),secureRandom);
            DefaultTlsClient client = new DefaultTlsClient() {
                public TlsAuthentication getAuthentication() throws IOException {
                TlsAuthentication auth = new TlsAuthentication() {
                    // Capture the server certificate information!
                    public void notifyServerCertificate(org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.Certificate serverCertificate) throws IOException {
                    }

                    public TlsCredentials getClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest) throws IOException {
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                return auth;
            }
            };
            protocol.connect(client);

       try {

            printSocketInfo(socket);

             socket.startHandshake();
         } catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println(e.toString()); 
         }
        finally {
             if (fis != null) {
                 fis.close();
             }
         }
        System.out.println("https.protocols "+System.getProperty("https.protocols"));
        System.out.println("Handler package >> "+System.getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs"));
        System.out.println("truststore>> "+System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
        System.out.println("truststore password>> "+System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"));
            }

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Socket class: "+s.getClass()); 
        System.out.println(" Remote address = " +s.getInetAddress().toString()); 
        System.out.println(" Remote port = "+s.getPort());
        System.out.println(" Local socket address = " +s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
        System.out.println(" Local address = " +s.getLocalAddress().toString()); 
        System.out.println(" Local port = "+s.getLocalPort()); System.out.println(" Need client authentication = " +s.getNeedClientAuth()); 
        SSLSession ss = s.getSession();

        System.out.println(" Cipher suite = "+ss.getCipherSuite());
        System.out.println(" Protocol = "+ss.getProtocol()); 
        }

            /**
     * Checks whether a file exists and can be opened.
     * @param file file to be checked.
     * @return FileInputStream to the file or <CODE>null</CODE> when it could
     * not be opened or didn't exist.
     */
    private static FileInputStream getFileInputStream(final File file)  {
    try {
        return AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedExceptionAction<FileInputStream>() {
                    public FileInputStream run() {
                        try {
                            if (file.exists()) {
                                return new FileInputStream(file);
                            } else {
                                return null;
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (PrivilegedActionException e)   {
        // Somehow we cannot run this, hence cannot read the file either...
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

**It still gives me handshake error and socket closed connection for bouncycastle.. Please help out..**

```html
  [#|2016-05-10T17:05:59.270+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|%% Cached cl ient session: [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:05:59.270+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 114|#]
    
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.270+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.270+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.270+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|, RECV TLSv1  ALERT:  |#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.270+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|warning, |#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.270+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|close_notify |#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.271+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called closeInternal(false)|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.271+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.271+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|, SEND TLSv1  ALERT:  |#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.271+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|warning, |#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.271+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|description  = close_notify|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.271+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.271+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.275+0800|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;_RequestID =c90ab4e4-5d4d-4ccb-802c-ca2050ba0ec8;|java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1372)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:44)
            at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:58)
            at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.RecordStream.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
            at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.safeWriteRecord(Unknown Source)
            at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.raiseAlert(Unknown Source)
            at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.failWithError(Unknown Source)
            at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
            at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.completeHandshake(Unknown Source)
            at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
            at ml.token.utility.TrustStore.setTruststore(TrustStore.java:107)
            at ml.token.utility.Challenge.getChallenge2(Challenge.java:233)
            at org.apache.jsp.jsp.process2_jsp._jspService(process2_jsp.java from :1312)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
            at com.mibs.XSSfilter.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:41)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
            at com.mibs.servlet.AccessPathCheckFilter.doFilter(AccessPathCheckFilter.java:76)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
            at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:670)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:601)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:875)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:365)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:285)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:221)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:393)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:269)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:111)
    
    and 
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.691+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 75|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.691+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 101|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.692+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.692+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.692+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|, RECV TLSv1  ALERT:  |#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.692+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|fatal, |#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.693+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|handshake_fa ilure|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.693+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called closeSocket()|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.693+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.694+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called close()|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.694+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called closeInternal(true)|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.694+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called close()|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.694+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called closeInternal(true)|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.694+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called close()|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.694+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|httpSSLWorke rThread-8080-4, called closeInternal(true)|#]
    
    [#|2016-05-10T17:06:59.698+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-4;|process2.jsp : challengeKey: [ERROR]com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure|#]
```

Comment: Could you provide the failure error/message that you encounter, when trying to connect?

Comment: Hi Castaglia.. Here is the error I receive when I try to receive the challange key..After calling setTruststore..
challengeKey: [ERROR]com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure|#]

Comment: @Anju Don't squeeze additional information into comments. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Hi Robert.. Noted, Thank you.

Comment: Can anybody help please? Im still awaiting solution..